# What kind of tensorflow operations would be executed on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I enable the log which indicates which devices tensorflow ops are executed on by following codes.

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

I got the output as below:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op LogicalNot in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op Assert in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op VarIsInitializedOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op LogicalNot in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op Assert in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op RandomUniform in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op Sub in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:611] Executing op Mul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

I wonder whether tensorflow has a document describing what kinds of ops are executed on GPU.